# VC++ Winsock2 Error 10049. Trying to build IRC bot

Tags: sockets, networking, irc, winsock2

I'm trying to port my IRC bot from Python to C++ and I'm running into some issues with Winsock2. I'm fairly new to sockets in C/C++ and most of this code was pieced together from various tutorials. I keep getting error 10049 and am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

port_ is set to 6667 and host_ is "irc.rizon.net"

```
WSADATA wsaData;
int starterr = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (starterr != 0) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << " occurred!" << std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "WSAStartup Successful!" << std::endl;
socketfd_ = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (socketfd_ == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << " occurred!" << std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "Socket Creation Successful!" << std::endl;

sockaddr_in anews;
anews.sin_port = htons(port_);
anews.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host_.c_str());
anews.sin_family = AF_INET;
if (connect(socketfd_,(sockaddr*)&anews, sizeof(anews)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << WSAGetLastError() << " occurred!" << std::endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
std::cout << "Socket has connected successfuly!" << std::endl;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`inet_addr()` takes a dotted IP address of the form "x.x.x.x" you are passing it the host name.

You can use `gethostbyname()`:

```
hostent* host;
char* ip;

...

// Get the local host information
host= gethostbyname(host_.c_str());
ip= inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)*host->h_addr_list);

sockaddr_in anews;
anews.sin_port = htons(port_);
anews.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
anews.sin_family = AF_INET;

...
```

Or an easier route would be to use getaddrinfo():

```
struct addrinfo *ai;

if(getaddrinfo(host_.c_str(), "6667", NULL, &ai) != 0)
    return 1;

socketfd_ = socket(ai->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (socketfd_ == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    return 1
}

if (connect(socketfd_, ai->ai_addr, (int)ai->ai_addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    closesocket(socketfd_);
    freeaddrinfo(ai);
    return 1;
}

...
```

Comment: It's complaining about ai not being initialized now. :\

Comment: `ai` shouldn't need to be initialized since it is an out parameter though you could initialize it to `NULL` before it's passed to `getaddrinfo()`. That would be a best practice anyway but I'm sure it's not your problem. You are still doing `WSAStartup()` right?

Comment: I tried initializing it to NULL only to get the same complaint. I'm also still using WSAStartup().

Comment: I'm sorry it's not the same complaint when I initialize it to NULL, it's a memory access violation by getaddrinfo().

Comment: When not using NULL and continuing the program past the initialization warning, it's complaining of an access violation by socket()

Comment: So, basically my example is an abbreviated version of the examples shown [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (about half way down) which works fine in my test application. Note that `ai` is a pointer type that receives the address of a linked list created by `getaddrinfo()`. Also note, the port is passed as a character string, not an integer. Without seeing your updated code it's hard to guess where your access violation might be coming from.